# Flutter model that updates itself

Tags: function, flutter, model

To develop my application I want to use a model that I created because I have to show this Widget in 3 pages.

This widget has a function, called when the widget is tapped and a text and color that should change when the button is been tapped.
This should happen just when the `userID` of the list `items`(The items are a list of user data and the list is structured like `[{''userID' : 'keykeykey, 'userName': 'Ryan', ...}, {..}, {..}]) is equal to the`userID` of the logged user.

For the purpose of this question I created a little widget (but the original one has al lot of more stuff in it

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeRandomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  SomeRandomCard({@required this.onPressed, this.text, this.color});

  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  String text;
  Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Text(text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: color
      ),),
      onPressed: onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

And I call the SomeRandomCard widget inside the `ListView.builder`:

```
userID = 'TestTestTestTestTestTestTest';
String text = 'a';
Color color = Colors.green;

  changeText(someID) {
    if (someID == userID) {
      setState(() {
        print(text);
        if (text == 'a') {
          text = 'b';
          color = Colors.green;
        } else {
          text = 'a';
          color = Colors.red;
        }
      });
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: style.coral,
      body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder
        (
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return SomeRandomCard(onPressed: changeText(items[index]['userID']), text: text, color: color,);
          }
      )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MyFloatingButton(),
    );
  }
```

But the text and the color dosen't change and the function is not been called.

I thought that the refresh problem was caused by the `StatelessWidget` then I edit the model and wrote this `StatefulWidget`:

```
class SomeRandomCard extends StatefulWidget {
  SomeRandomCard({@required this.onPressed, this.text, this.color});

  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  String text;
  Color color;


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _SomeRandomCardState();
}

class _SomeRandomCardState extends State<SomeRandomCard> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Text(widget.text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: widget.color
      ),),
      onPressed: widget.onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

But as before the function is not been called.

I know that the real problem is the variable when i call the function, because if i created a new function that dosen't require a parameter

```
SomeRandomCard(onPressed: changeText, text: text, color: color,);
```

the function is been called and change the value on the screen.

But I have to check if the userId is the same, how can I do it?

Comment: What are `items` here?

Comment: The `items` are a list of user data and each user object is structured like `{''userID' : 'keykeykey, 'userName': 'Ryan', ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix:

Don't do this:

```
onPressed: widget.onPressed
```

Do this:

```
onPressed: () => widget.onPressed()
```

Here is the complete code for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyStateWidget());
}

class MyStateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStateWidgetState createState() => _MyStateWidgetState();
}

class _MyStateWidgetState extends State<MyStateWidget> {
  var userID = 'TestTestTestTestTestTestTest';
  String text = 'a';
  Color color = Colors.green;

  changeText(someID) {
    debugPrint("changeText");
    if (someID == userID) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint(text);
        if (text == 'a') {
          text = 'b';
          color = Colors.green;
        } else {
          text = 'a';
          color = Colors.red;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                  return SomeRandomCard(
                    onPressed: () => changeText(items[index]['userID']),
                    text: text,
                    color: color,
                  );
                })),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {print("Hello");},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeRandomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  SomeRandomCard({@required this.onPressed, this.text, this.color});

  final Function onPressed;
  String text;
  Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: color),
      ),
      onPressed: () => onPressed(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the real problem betweeen

`SomeRandomCard(onPressed: changeText(items[index]['userID']), text: text, color: color,);`

and

`SomeRandomCard(onPressed: changeText, text: text, color: color,);`

The first one, you pass a `void` or nothing(`null`) to `onPressed` because you called `changeText`, and changeText return `void`.

The second one works because you passed an actual `function` instead of `null` or `void`.

According to your requirement.

> the function is been called and change the value on the screen.
>   But I have to check if the userId is the same, how can I do it?

You could do It as below:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: style.coral,
      body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder
        (
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return SomeRandomCard(onPressed: () { changeText(items[index]['userID']) }, text: text, color: color,);
          }
      )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: MyFloatingButton(),
    );
  }
```

By the way, It might be confusion on the preservation of `index`. I had this confusion before, so I provide a minimal exmaple, you could try It on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) to see how It works.

```dart
class TestCallback {
  final Function onPress;
  TestCallback(this.onPress);

  call() {
    onPress();
  }
}

main(){
  List<TestCallback> callbacks = new List<TestCallback>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    callbacks.add(TestCallback((){ print(i); }));
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    callbacks[i].call();
}
```

Output:
`0 1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just change `onPressed: changeText(items[index]['userID'])` to `onPressed: ()=>changeText(items[index]['userID'])`will work.